# Change Web API LocalHost to Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, api, https, powerapps

I create a web API that gets data from a SQL Table
it works but it gives a url with "LocalHost"

eg. http://localhost:6121/Api/Users

How can I modifed that LocalHost so I can access from other computers and be able to use it in PowerApps platform

Comment: Did you host it in to a server? If So you may use it as `http://YourHost/Api/Users`

Comment: I create the API on my personal lap

Comment: If I create the same API , but now in the server it will change the localhost to the server name? and be able to use it outside the server?

Comment: Just do it and see, I assume you have an IIS running in the Server

Comment: >> *I create the API on my personal lap*. most of us are doing the same. once everything works, then we will publish that to a server or to a 3rd party host or cloud